# Google gson parser giving OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, out-of-memory, gson

I am parsing a response string and sorting it. This is fine if the response is small but if the response is large then it gives OOM Error at `parse` method.

```
public class Parser {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String response = "Long Response String";
    Parser parser = new Parser();
    String sorted = parser.sortGpupResponse(response);
    System.out.println("the sorted..."+sorted);
}

public String sortGpupResponse(String response) {
    JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(response); //OOM Error
    JsonArray jsonarray = jelement.getAsJsonArray();
    List<JsonObject> array = new ArrayList<JsonObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.size(); i++) {
        array.add(jsonarray.get(i).getAsJsonObject());
    }
    Collections.sort(array, new Comparator<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(JsonObject lhs, JsonObject rhs) {
            Long lid = lhs.get("begin").getAsLong();
            Long rid = rhs.get("begin").getAsLong();
            return lid.compareTo(rid);
        }
    });
    return array.toString();
}
}
```

**LOG:**

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Failed parsing JSON source: JsonReader at line 1 column 23699433 to Json
        at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:88)
        at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:59)
        at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:45)
    at com.project.user.User.sortedResponse(SortedResponse.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextQuotedValue(JsonReader.java:1014)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextName(JsonReader.java:798)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25.read(TypeAdapters.java:667)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25.read(TypeAdapters.java:659)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25.read(TypeAdapters.java:642)
        at com.google.gson.internal.Streams.parse(Streams.java:44)
        at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:84)
```

Comment: Could you supply JVM arg values for -Xmx and -Xms ?

Comment: @RazvanManolescu - `-Xms1024M -Xmx4096M`

Comment: How large are we talking about here?

Comment: This is large response from API usually a `80M` size or more at times.

Comment: I was recently writing to and then reading from json files using Gson that were around 1Gb of size, and since it was a part of a university exercise, we did it for days. I did it in Eclipse under Win 7, however, with a custom eclipse.ini file (-Xms512m -Xmx2048m). I never got this exception.

Comment: There is one post that says that it can be done using Gson Streaming: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26006773/outofmemoryerror-when-using-gson-to-parse-a-large-json-response. Any more idea on how to do this in my case?

Comment: See if this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230744/json-parser-read-an-entry-by-entry-from-large-json-file) helps. I think its for same kind of problem